# What are the agent action APIs available for deepsecurity API on DS12

Tags: deepsecurity

I'm using python SDK for deep security 12 to automate deep security agent actions such as reactivate. deactivate and activate on a on-premise Trend deep security infrastructure.

I was unable to find the exact API calls for the agent actions on https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/fr/api-reference?platform=on-premise.

It would be very helpful if someone can advise me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Activating and deactivating computers via API is only currently available in the older SOAP API, as explained here: https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/fr/transition-from-the-soap-api?platform=on-premise

PS. I work for Trend Micro on Deep Security